# Jquery placing random text inside a circle div

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to generate random text inside a circle div but it is displaying out of circle.

Looking for some pointers to fix this issue.

This is what i've tried http://jsfiddle.net/q58HK/12/

Thanks

Comment: I tried to mess around with some values and came up with this: http://jsfiddle.net/q58HK/28/

the words are placed outside the circle because the whitespace around the circle still counts as your div. A div is and will always be a square :)

Comment: hmmm try to add a width and height... no idea on how to do it though

Answer (score 1):

You may try this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/aalmeida/2Bk4v/

edited: I made another version, a bit faster: http://jsfiddle.net/aalmeida/2Bk4v/3/